# SemanticImport mangles Greek letters in column headers

Tags: bugs, import, unicode, tsv-format

**Bug persisting through 13.1.0**

---

I have a `Dataset` whose column headers contain Greek letters. If I export the Dataset as a csv file and then `SemanticImport` that file, the Greek letters appear incorrectly:

```
    data = Dataset[{ 
            <|"\[Epsilon]" -> 1.5, "\[Eta]" -> 1.0, "\[Nu]u" -> 5.3, "\[Mu]u" -> 3.23, "x0" -> 3.0 |>,
            <|"\[Epsilon]" -> 2.5, "\[Eta]" -> 2.0, "\[Nu]u" -> 5.4, "\[Mu]u" -> 15.3, "x0" -> 4.1 |>
        }];
    Export["test.csv", data, "csv", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
    data2 = SemanticImport["test.csv", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
```

The result is: [image: data2]

I can open the csv file with Excel to see that the Greek letters have been exported correctly. They are also imported correctly into Mathematica if I use `Import` instead of `SemanticImport`. (I know that I can convert the result of `Import` into a dataset as a workaround.)

I'm using Mathematica 13.1 on MacOS 11.6 (BigSur).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `SemanticImport` simply ignores the `CharacterEncoding` option and imports as `"String"` instead. Compare with

```
Import["test.csv", "String"]
```

> "Ïµ","Î·","Î½u","Î¼u","x0"
>
> 1.5,1.,5.3,3.23,3.
>
> 2.5,2.,5.4,15.3,4.1

The same is true for `SemanticImportString`:

```
SemanticImportString[Import["test.csv", "Text"]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

It think it is a bug in `SemanticImport`, please report it to the official support.

As a workaround, use `Import`:

```
Import["test.csv", "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1]
```

> [image: screenshot]